# Pandas DataFrames: Extract Information and Collapse Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame which contains information in columns which I would like to extract into a new column.

It is best explained visually:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Number Type 1':[1,2,np.nan],
                   'Number Type 2':[np.nan,3,4],
                   'Info':list('abc')})
```

[image: Initial DataFrame]

The Table shows the initial DataFrame with `Number Type 1` and `NumberType 2` columns.
I would like to extract the types and create a new `Type` column, refactoring the DataFrame accordingly.

[image: Refactored DataFrame]

basically, Numbers are collapsed into the `Number` columns, and the types extracted into the `Type` column. The information in the `Info` column is bound to the numbers (f.e. 2 and 3 have the same information b)

What is the best way to do this in Pandas?

Comment: [Please don't upload images of code/data on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df = df.melt('Info', value_name='Number', var_name='Type').dropna(subset=['Number'])
df['Type'] = df['Type'].str.extract('(\d+)')
df['Number'] = df['Number'].astype(int)
print (df)
  Info Type  Number
0    a    1       1
1    b    1       2
4    b    2       3
5    c    2       4
```

Another solution with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df = df.set_index('Info').stack().rename_axis(('Info','Type')).reset_index(name='Number')

df['Type'] = df['Type'].str.extract('(\d+)')
df['Number'] = df['Number'].astype(int)
print (df)
  Info Type  Number
0    a    1       1
1    b    1       2
2    b    2       3
3    c    2       4
```

Comment: Thanks! How would it work, if all the types are strings?

Comment: @user3142067 - Same way, only remove `df['Number'] = df['Number'].astype(int)`

Comment: Ok, I see. The Number column is type object by default. What confused me is that longer numbers are still transformed to this representation: 8.0756e+19 .
Is this normal to happen for numbers encoded as strings?